# Pilosa k8s pod crashloopbackoff with error "server : executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: kubernetes, executable, kubernetes-helm, file-not-found, pilosa

I am preparing a helm chart for pilosa. After installing the chart (or while creating the deployment),
the pilosa pod enters to a CrashLoopBackOff.

This is the rendered YAML file for the k8s deployment.

```
# Source: pilosa/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: RELEASE-NAME-pilosa
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: pilosa-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: pilosa
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: pilosa
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: pilosa
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-cr-secret
      serviceAccountName: default
      securityContext:
        {}
      initContainers:
        - command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - |
            sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=600
            sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60
            sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3
          image: busybox
          name: init-sysctl
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
      containers:
        - name: pilosa
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "mycr.azurecr.io/pilosa:v1.4.0"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command:
            - server
            - --data-dir
            - /data
            - --max-writes-per-request
            - "20000"
            - --bind
            - http://pilosa:10101
            - --cluster.coordinator=true
            - --gossip.seeds=pilosa:14000
            - --handler.allowed-origins="*"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 10101
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          volumeMounts:
            - name: "pilosa-pv-storage"
              mountPath: /data
          resources:
            {}
      volumes:
      - name: pilosa-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pilosa-pv-claim
```

When checked the reason for that i found:

```
$ kubectl describe pod pilosa-57cb7b8764-knsmw
.

.

Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  48s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/pilosa-57cb7b8764-knsmw to 10.0.10.3
  Normal   Pulling    47s                kubelet            Pulling image "busybox"
  Normal   Pulled     45s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox"
  Normal   Created    45s                kubelet            Created container init-sysctl
  Normal   Started    45s                kubelet            Started container init-sysctl
  Normal   Pulling    45s                kubelet            Pulling image "mycr.azurecr.io/pilosa:v1.2.0"
  Normal   Pulled     15s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "mycr.azurecr.io/pilosa:v1.2.0"
  Normal   Created    14s (x2 over 15s)  kubelet            Created container pilosa
  Warning  Failed     14s (x2 over 15s)  kubelet            Error: failed to start container "pilosa": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"server\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
  Normal   Pulled     14s                kubelet            Container image "mycr.azurecr.io/pilosa:v1.2.0" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    10s                kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

That means the problem is it cannot run command server :

```
 Error: failed to start container "pilosa": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"server\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

But that command is available in pilosa as specified here : https://www.pilosa.com/docs/latest/installation/

Can anyone help me to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that Kubernetes is overriding the `ENTRYPOINT` in the Pilosa Docker image. The `server` command is actually a subcommand of `pilosa`, which works because of how the Pilosa Dockerfile defines the command:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/pilosa"]
CMD ["server", "--data-dir", "/data", "--bind", "http://0.0.0.0:10101"]
```

Because you are using the `command:` declaration, it overrides both the `ENTRYPOINT` and the `CMD` when invoking the container.

I think the simple solution is to replace `command:` with `args:`, and I believe k8s will no longer override the `ENTRYPOINT`. Or you could instead add `/pilosa` to the front of the command.

You may also take a look at this Pilosa helm chart, which is unmaintained but might work for you. Note that it uses a StatefulSet instead of a Deployment, which should fit Pilosa better: https://github.com/pilosa/helm

Comment: Yes, after doing that the pod is still crashLoopBackOff  with error: "Error: running server: setting up server: getting listener: net.Listen: listen tcp 10.96.146.102:10101: bind: cannot assign requested address" !

Comment: Keep the bind address as `--bind http://0.0.0.0:10101`.  The form you have now is probably trying to bind to the matching Service's IP address, which won't work.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried that. And now the pod is running. But I actually didn't properly understood the reason behind it ! And, the pod still gives an error log 
"Failed to join 10.96.183.208: dial tcp 10.96.193.108:14000: i/o timeout" even if it is running.

Comment: The above mentioned error log also got fixed when in used arg `--gossip.seeds=0.0.0.0:14000` instead of `--gossip.seeds=pilosa:14000` ! Why binding to matching service's IP is not working? I was using `--bind http://pilosa:10101` previously and it was working. The difference is that previously i was using pilosa image `v1.2.0`, and now it is `v1.4.0`. Is that causing this problem?